# Слишком большие интервалы

Tags: google-api, диаграммы

Как можно избавиться от длинных пустых промежутков на графиках построенных с помощью google chart? 
Вот общее отображение данных за несколько часов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И не заметно, как есть данные в первые секунды, но если сузить диапазон просмотра, то заметим, что нужная информация скрыта под громоздким пустым диапазоном.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из документации, вам необходимо поставить параметр **interpolateNulls** в **true** (по умолчанию false)

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: Что-то не выходит.

Comment: Можно пример данных на вход?

Comment: Вот входные данные. http://jsfiddle.net/n3Lz7vdr/ 
Я бы приложил весь код, но когда весь прикладываю со всеми зависимостями, то не сохраняется пример.